# What is a "BEA bag"?

Tags: meaning

I read this in an Agatha Christie novel from 1965:

> He certainly left here on Thursday evening carrying his BEA bag.

What is a BEA bag? Is it a brand or a specific type of bag? Googling doesn't yield very specific results.

Comment: Karin, in that era it was quite trendy to use an airline bag (originally they were given away freely by the various airlines of the day), as your hand bag or perhaps sports bag. So at that time if you said "a TWA Bag" "a BOAC bag" "a JAL bag" or the like, what it meant was one of those particularly-sized zip-bags with a logo on it. (In other words, any phrase "airline-name bag" was understood to mean "airline bag".) By way of example, in Hong Kong in that era, for schoolchildren, the only bag to use as a schoolbag was an airline bag. Airline bags of that era are now collectible.

Comment: For reference, the novel is "At Bertram's Hotel".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That BEA is capitalised suggests an abbreviation, indicating a BEA bag is a bag *of* or *from* BEA.

It's not a type of bag more a branded bag; a Starbucks bag is a bag from Starbucks not a bag of the Starbucks type.

BEA can stand for British European Airways, "a British airline which existed from 1946 until 1974"<sup>1</sup>.

The period of operation of the airline fits the year of publication of the novel. That the airline was British fits with Christie being British *and* that the airline was "the largest domestic airline within the United Kingdom"<sup>1</sup> supports the notion that Christie and the intended audience of the novel would have been aware of what BEA at the time was.

Context suggests Christie refers to a bag supplied by British Europeans Airlines, possibly sold to or offered to passengers.

[image: BEA airline bag]

<sup>1</sup> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_European_Airways

Comment: Those of use with [BOAC bags](http://www.google.com/search?q=boac+bag&tbm=isch) regarded those with BEA bags as rather less adventurous or classy.

Comment: Back in the days when air travel was an elegant pleasure rather than slightly preferable to be dragged behind a horse - the airlines gave these bags to customers so you could advertise the ariline and that you were a stylish international jet-setter